# Scale svg content to fit page size (or vice versa) without inkscape

Tags: svg, graphics, crop, scaling

I want to scale an SVG image to fit the page size (or vice versa: crop the page to fit is contents). This can be done using inkscape as described [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21635/getting-rid-of-whitespace-in-inkscape). However, there seems to be no way of doings this without gui. Using actions and verbs via the command line will always require GUI. Is there an alternative way of archieving this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear: anyway you may need to get the bounding box of the image and use it to redefine the viewBox of the svg element. Also you may need to remove the width and height of the svg element. Please edit your question and add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear as to what you wish to ask specifically, I am answering if you wish to

### Scale Svg to ft the page size in HTML document

If you change the viewBox property of SVG to a different ratio than the height and width ratio of the image than the SVG will not fit the page as by default there is a property to `<svg>` tag called `PreserveAspactRatio` that is set to `meet` by default. You will have to change this property to clip so that the SVG fills the complete viewport.

The image will distort if you define different aspect ratio than the ratio of height and width of SVG but it will fill the page nontheless.

Just add this code in  tag and you're good.

```
preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin slice"
```

It can have different arguments before slice namely

```
none
```

Do not force uniform scaling. Scale the graphic content of the given element non-uniformly (without preserving aspect ratio) if necessary such that the element's bounding box exactly matches the viewport rectangle.

```
xMinYMin
```

Force uniform scaling.
Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest X value of the viewport.
Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest Y value of the viewport.

```
xMinYMid
```

Force uniform scaling.
Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest X value of the viewport.
Align the midpoint Y value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint Y value of the viewport.

```
xMaxYMax
```

Force uniform scaling.
Align the + of the element's viewBox with the maximum X value of the viewport.
Align the + of the element's viewBox with the maximum Y value of the viewport.
etc..

For more details, you can refer to [this](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/#:%7E:text=The%20viewBox%20attribute%20takes%20four,y%3E%20%2C%20width%20and%20height%20.&text=The%20and,and%20height%20of%20that%20viewBox.) article if your problem is related to web specifically.